# How do I make sure entered integer is greater than current value before updating model field?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am using a form that saves to one model to update the most current mileage which is stored in another model. I want to make sure the mileage entered is > or = the current mileage. I havent been able to figure out the right validation or where to write the validation.

I have tried an if statement in the form_valid() of the CreateView and a save() method in the model.

Models.py

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     make = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     model = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
     vin = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=17)
     gvw = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
     license_plate = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
     purchase_date = models.DateField()
     current_mileage = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

   class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('vehicles:vehicle_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    @property
    def get_current_mileage(self):
         return self.current_mileage


class FuelEntry(models.Model):
     vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     fuel_choices = (
         ('EMPTY', 'Empty'),
         ('1/8', '1/8'),
         ('1/4', '1/4'),
         ('1/2', '1/2'),
         ('3/4', '3/4'),
         ('FULL', 'Full'),
    )
     current = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=fuel_choices)
     after = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=fuel_choices, blank=True)
     gallons = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, blank=True, default='0')
     cost = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, blank=True, default='0')
     mileage = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['-date', 'vehicle']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vehicle.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('fuellog:entry_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Views.py

```
class CreateEntry(CreateView):
    model = FuelEntry
    fields = ('vehicle', 'current', 'after', 'gallons', 'cost', 'mileage')

    def form_valid(self,form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        vehicle_id = self.object.vehicle.pk
        mileage = self.object.mileage
        self.object.save()

        current_mileage = Vehicle.objects.filter(id=vehicle_id).get('current_mileage')
        if current_mileage > mileage:
            raise ValidationError('Incorrect mileage reading')



    Vehicle.objects.filter(id=vehicle_id).update(current_mileage=mileage)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

ValueError at /fuel/new
too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: You should do it in the clean method of the form.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Can you provide some insight or a link to where I might find the correct way to do that? Do I need to create a modelForm instead of using the CreateView?

Comment: You can use CreateView but you need to tell it to use the form you have defined yourself with a suitable clean method. Define `form_class` in `CreateEntry` instead of `fields`.